# How to make svg element to move around a svg path?

Tags: javascript, svg

I just dont know how to do that, and how to google it

[Here's what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BFLm.gif)

Help?

Comment: You may do this using SMIL animations. Please read about [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion). You can also do it using javascript, but it's a little bit more complicated. Please try `animateMotion` and if you can't do it ask another question showing what you've tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the solution
its a stroke, and you just need to play with

**stroke-dasharray
stroke-dashoffset**

Have fun !